# "Super-duper ultra mega"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Can I use the adjectives *super-duper*, *ultra*, and *mega* in one adjective? For example,

> A **super-duper ultra mega** huge dome.

Comment: Related: Peter Griffin's bunka busta mega ultra super ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkVguDb6otc

Comment: You can if you wish your writing style to be judged by such childish exaggeration. An educated person would write something like “extremely large”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you could - but I'd restrict it's usage to informal writing, in cases where you wanted to use hyperbole for some dramatic or humorous effect.  For starters, the term *super-duper* is considered slang, so it generally wouldn't work well in a formal document.

Moreover, you have more three adjectives describing *dome*, meaning that commas are in order.  Plus, ultra- and mega- are prefixes, so I'd punctuate the sentence as follows:

*On our way through Texas, we visited a super-duper, ultra-, mega-huge dome!*

All in all, though, that sentence has rather juvenile overtones - which could be fine, of course, depending on the context.

Comment: I'd be inclined to hyphenate the whole thing together _super-duper-ultra-mega-huge-dome_.

Comment: @neil: No, the hyphen __must__ go between super and duper, and between ultra and mega, but __definitely not__ between duper and ultra. That would be wrong.

Comment: @Mitch I'd put it like neil says, except not between "huge" and "dome".  Stringing _all_ the adjectives together gives it a slight monotone, and emphasizes all of them.

Comment: I didn't mean to start a super-duper, ultra-mega-huge debate...

Comment: @izkata: commas are right out.

Answer (score 13):

Sure, if you want to sound like an excited nine-year-old.